# if user is trying for login 1st time in drupal

Tags: drupal, authentication, passwords

I have imported all my EE site users in to Drupal site but I would like to redirect user if they are trying to login 1st time in drupal site then I would like to redirect user to forget password page.  is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can hook login form to execute your code when form is prepared to be rendered:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7

Then, you can set some cookie and check for it. If cookie is there means it's not first time. And if there is no cookie then do redirection.